# Google maps Rectangle API - adding a background image

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using a Google Maps Rectangle [as seen here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-simple).

I'm looking at the [Rectangle options api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#RectangleOptions) and there's nothing about adding an image - only border and background color options. I was wondering if there's another way to do it? I'd like to have the border, but just put a background image instead of a colour.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by [adding a custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) to your map.

You initialize the map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
```

Then by setting bounds you indicate how large the image will by it's width.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
        new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));
```

Indicate the source of  your image.

```
var srcImage = 'your_path/your_image.png';
```

Then create the new Overlay.

```
overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
```

Comment: Thanks Franco, this looks like the better way of doing it! Much appreciated.